# Counter glitching? Instability? Can't get a trigger lock on the scope, what might that be?

Tags: debugging, glitch, 74ls161

I have a 4 MHz clock and 4 x 74LS161 4-bit counters hooked up to get a 16 bit counter. It's all done how I have done it many times, synchronous with clock going into all the counters and RCO of previous stage hooked to ENT of the next.

[image]

It's not the first time I'm using the '161 counter. But maybe the first time I'm using it in 16 bit configuration. What's happening is at the higher stages, e.g., chip 3 bit 2 (of 0 to 3), i.e., bit 10, the output starts to wiggle horizontally on the analog scope and I can't get a stable triggering.

[image]

This happens not if I just have the counter count with outputs without load, but it happens when I connect the output to the 74LS652 bus transceiver / registers. This is the same setup that I ran successfully with 74HC393 and 74HC4040, and the transceiver output enable on the input side is disabled fixed so I know I don't get output contention here.

I am also pretty sure my power is plenty of 5V and clean. It's breadboard, but I am fairly neat working with breadboard and I have had very good results with my setup. Only now that I moved to the 74LS161 counter (which I actually knew better than the 4040) suddenly I get this wiggle problem. And it's not in the fast lower stages, it is in the higher stages, bit 10 to 15 getting worse as we go up.

What could cause this and how can I debug this (with only an analog scope, no digital waveform capture device.)

Comment: RCO latency?....  jumper crosstalk?

Comment: Report on signal integrity and frequency dependance on false trigger.

Comment: You will find glitches on the later RCO outputs. These don't matter if CK is correctly connected. But what have you done with LD? Hopefully pulled high, not floating. Ad do you have adequate decoupling right next to each chip?

Comment: Yes, LD is pulled high. All but the inputs are not connected. I guess I can try to pull the inputs low. But I don't have much hope.

No wires crossed because it is working when the output is left open and yes I did have some wires crossed until it was all debugged to the state where I made my post. I always use my posts here as a chance to go over things once again to make sure I'm not wasting time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, as the commenters asked, the best explanation for counters glitching after everything else on them is connected right, is that the outputs are connected to other components that have something wrong with them. Outputs connected to outputs. And it turns out that meticulously tracing it through disconnecting all the wires and connecting them, and even using an analogue Ampere-meter I found that there was current coming out of an input pin of one of the following 74LS652 bus transceivers.